# Is there a way to make MS Word or LO Writer to automatically indent paragraphs in a section except for the first paragraph?

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word

I would like to make a style in MS Word or LO Writer that will leave the first paragraph of a section or chapter (i.e. anything that follows a heading) unindended, but indent all the paragraphs that follow in the same section.

I think there is a way to do that with LaTeX, but I would like to find out if I can do it in those popular text editors as well.

Comment: You should try asking this on the stack exchange Super user :) https://superuser.com/ questions about word fit there better then here.

Answer (score 1):

In Word, the easiest way to do this is to use the Next Paragraph Style option in the styles. After a section have the next paragraph style be First Paragraph (or somesuch) which won't have the indentation and have the next paragraph style for First Paragraph be Body which will be indented.

That said, I don't bother with much typographic nicety working in Word. I focus on the writing and leave typographic niceties for other situations. Having been a typographer at one point it pains me a little to do so, but it's rare that the output of Word is the final presentation of the writing in any event.